# does okhttp check for whether the response is complete or not for chunked responses

Tags: android, kotlin, okhttp

I am receiving a big file from the server which I cannot hold in memory, hence receiving it in chunked encoded response and reading it through the okhttp `Response.body().source()` into a buffer and writing it to a file as below.

```kotlin
val downloadFileBuffer = ByteArray(1024)

client.newCall(request).enqueue(object : Callback {
            override fun onFailure(call: Call, e: IOException) {
                Log.d("DOCUMENT_CONVERSION", "FAILED", e)
            }

            override fun onResponse(call: Call, response: Response) {
                if (response.isSuccessful) {
                    val source = response.body()?.source()
                    while (!source?.exhausted()!!) {
                        source?.read(downloadFileBuffer)
                        downloadFileStream.write(downloadFileBuffer) // downloadFileStream being a FileOutputStream
                    }
                    response.close()

                } else {
                    // error handling
                    response.close()
                }
            }
        })
```

chunked responses will end with an empty zero byte chunk being received. In order to write the whole file on disk I need to check whether the whole response till the end zero byte chunk has been received or not.

I want to know whether okhttp have an internal mechanism to check whether the chunked response is complete or not through `onFailure` or any other way or it should be handle at application level by me ? What if there is a network failure during the transfer and last few bytes would not have been recieved making the files corrupt ?

Answer (score 1):

onFailure won't be called if you get a chunked response and then it fails  during the response transfer.

You will receive an IOException from a call to source.read if the transfer does not complete.

A cleaner example of this loop is here https://github.com/square/okhttp/blob/c194980c7f0feee59c978766c1acf5c66167994c/okcurl/src/main/kotlin/okhttp3/curl/Main.kt#L139-L143

```
      val source = response.body!!.source()
      while (!source.exhausted()) {
        out.write(source.buffer, source.buffer.size)
        out.flush()
      }
```